# Finding the most commonly used non-stop words in a column

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, string-manipulation

Simply put, I have a Postgres column containing ordinary prose and would like to determine the `x` most commonly used words ("word" being a group of characters delimited by a space, but not being stop word) across all rows.

I've found two solutions that nearly hit the mark:

```
SELECT *                                       
FROM   ts_stat($$SELECT to_tsvector('english', title) FROM item$$) 
ORDER  BY ndoc DESC
LIMIT  50;
```

This is great, except it returns word stems.

```
SELECT   UNNEST(string_to_array(title, ' ')) AS word, COUNT(*) AS ct
FROM     item 
GROUP    BY 1 
ORDER    BY 2 DESC
LIMIT    50;
```

This one returns the full words, but includes stop words.

For the sake of simplicity: stop words are supposed to be found on `TABLE stop_words (lowercase_stopword text PRIMARY KEY)`.

Can anyone help me over the line?

Answer (score 6):

Your first query was pretty close. To remove the unwanted stemming, create a text search configuration with a simple dictionary that does not do it.

I suggest to use a separate schema for text search objects, but that's totally optional:

```
CREATE SCHEMA ts;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA ts TO public;
COMMENT ON SCHEMA ts IS 'text search objects';

CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY ts.english_simple_dict (
    TEMPLATE = pg_catalog.simple
  , STOPWORDS = english
);

CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION ts.english_simple (COPY = simple);
ALTER  TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION ts.english_simple
   ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword WITH ts.english_simple_dict;  -- 1, 'Word, all ASCII'
```

Then your **query** works, and very fast, too:

```
SELECT *                                       
FROM   ts_stat($$SELECT to_tsvector('ts.english_simple', title) FROM item$$) 
ORDER  BY ndoc DESC
LIMIT  50;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=970c9aaa93b5a820fd830e849db0cb14)*

This operates with lower case words without stemming and doesn't break for non-ASCII letters.

### Backgroud

Read the [chapter **Simple Dictionary**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SIMPLE-DICTIONARY) in the manual.

The exact definition of a "word" is a tricky matter. The default text search parser (currently it's the only one) identifies 23 different types of tokens. See:

```
SELECT * FROM ts_token_type('default');
```

Built-in text search configurations map most of those to (built-in) dictionaries. Mappings for the `english` config:

```
SELECT tt.*, m.mapdict::regdictionary AS dictionary
FROM   pg_ts_config_map m
LEFT   JOIN   ts_token_type(3722) tt ON tt.tokid = m.maptokentype
WHERE  mapcfg = 'english'::regconfig  --  'ts.english_simple'::regconfig
ORDER  BY tt.tokid;
```

The demo above creates a new config based on the `simple` config, and since all English [stop words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-STOPWORDS) are of type 'asciiword', we only need to map this type to remove stop words, no stemming or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

**[Erwin's answer is better](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/186754/2639)**

Following the sample data from [@joanolo above](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/160929/2639), I wanted to answer in such a way that did **not** require you to explicitly list stop words. Doing so requires assumptions about the dictionary.

```
WITH titles(title) AS
(
   VALUES 
      ('This is a title'), 
      ('This is another title'), 
      ('This is finally a third title'), 
      ('and I don''t like Mondays')
)
SELECT token, count(*)
FROM titles
CROSS JOIN LATERAL ts_debug(title)
WHERE alias = 'asciiword'
        AND array_length(lexemes,1) <> 0
GROUP BY token;

  token  | count 
---------+-------
 title   |     3
 another |     1
 like    |     1
 third   |     1
 Mondays |     1
 finally |     1
(6 rows)
```

We're using [`array_length` to get around an internal bug described here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/186715/2639)

Comment: `ts_debug()` is very expensive since it does a lot of work we don't need for the query. Plus, this would fail for non-ASCII characters. And we probably don't want it case sensitive, either. Actually, all we need is a text search configuration that doesn't stem. I added another solution.

Answer (score 1):

This would give you your expected output:

```
-- Some example data
WITH titles(title) AS
(
   VALUES 
      ('This is a title'), 
      ('This is another title'), 
      ('This is finally a third title'), 
      ('and I don''t like Mondays')
)

-- List here all the words that you consider 'stop words'
-- in lowercase
, stop_words(word) AS
(

    VALUES ('the'), ('a'), ('and')
)

-- Make list of (lowercased) found words
, found_lower_words AS
(
SELECT 
    lower(unnest(string_to_array(title, ' '))) AS word
FROM
    titles
)

-- And now anti-join with the stop_words, group and count
SELECT
    word, count(*) AS word_count
FROM
    found_lower_words
    LEFT JOIN stop_words USING(word)
WHERE
    stop_words.word is NULL
GROUP BY
    word
ORDER BY
    word_count DESC, word ASC
LIMIT
    50 ;
```

The results would be:

```
  |---------+---|
  |   is    | 3 |
  |---------+---|
  |  this   | 3 |
  |---------+---|
  |  title  | 3 |
  |---------+---|
  | another | 1 |
  |---------+---|
  |  don't  | 1 |
  |---------+---|
  | finally | 1 |
  |---------+---|
  |    i    | 1 |
  |---------+---|
  |  like   | 1 |
  |---------+---|
  | mondays | 1 |
  |---------+---|
  |  third  | 1 |
  |---------+---|
```