# How do I select arrays that are not empty?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, null, array, condition

Why is this so tricky, what is token set to that it isn't equal to null nor an empty string?

```
SELECT lexemes
FROM ts_debug('This is a title')
WHERE alias = 'asciiword';

 lexemes 
---------
 {}
 {}
 {}
 {titl}
(4 rows)
```

Ok.. So I want to get rid of `{}`,

```
SELECT lexemes
FROM ts_debug('This is a title')
WHERE alias = 'asciiword'
  AND lexemes <> '{}'
  AND lexemes <> ARRAY[]::text[]
  AND lexemes IS NOT NULL
  AND lexemes <> ARRAY[' ']
  AND lexemes <> ARRAY[null]::text[];
```

**I knew most of these wouldn't work.**, but I'm totally confused why `<> '{}'` wouldn't work not `<> ARRAY[]::text;`. How do I filter this out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason seems to be that empty strings in that column have array dimensions `[1:0]`. Should normally be `NULL`. See:

```
SELECT lexemes, array_dims(lexemes) FROM ts_debug('a title');

 lexemes | array_dims
---------+------------
 {}      | [1:0]  -- !!
         |
 {titl}  | [1:1]
```

Empty arrays normally have NULL as array dimensions.

```
SELECT '{}'::text[] AS test, array_dims('{}'::text[]);

 test    | array_dims
---------+------------
 {}      | <NULL>
```

Hence, the comparison `lexemes = '{}'::text[]` returns `FALSE`. Looks like a bug to me. I tested versions 8.4 - 10 Beta. It's in all versions.

As a ***workaround***, to exclude *all* empty arrays including the odd case (and NULL):

```
SELECT *
FROM   ts_debug('This is a title')
WHERE  cardinality(lexemes) > 0;
```

Or compare the text representation:

```
...
AND    lexemes::text <> '{}';
```

[I filed bug report #14826.](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/20170923125723.1448.39412%40wrigleys.postgresql.org#20170923125723.1448.39412@wrigleys.postgresql.org)

Comment: Great, answer [I was using `array_length` yesterday but it seemed like an ugly work around](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/186702/2639). Being simply a bug explains a lot more. I wonder why Pg lets you create empty arrays with dimensionality.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: I wonder, too. And so does Tom Lane who sent in a patch to make `construct_[md_]array()` handle empty arrays correctly. So this should be fixed for good soon.

Comment: [The patch has been applied.](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=716ea626a88ac510523ab3af5bc779d78eeced58)  Not sure if it's released with Postgres 10, though, which is RC currently.