# 'text search dictionary "unaccent" does not exist' entries in postgres log, supposedly during automatic analyze

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, autovacuum, unaccent

I have many such entries in the postgresql main log, ever since upgrading to Postgres 10:

```
2018-03-28 08:51:00.281 CEST [97547] ERROR:  text search dictionary "unaccent" does not exist
2018-03-28 08:51:00.281 CEST [97547] CONTEXT:  automatic analyze of table "dbname.public.periodical"
```

I do use unaccent in many indexes in all tables (by making unaccent immutable (I know it is not the recommended way, but it is so historically)).

If I manually run `vacuumdb dbname --table periodical` or `VACUUM periodical` or `VACUUM ANALYZE periodical`, it does not generate such an error (neither on the command line, nor in the log).

Does anyone have a tip how I could stop these messages and what their real cause may be?

PostgreSQL version: 10.3 (Debian 10.3-1.pgdg80+1)

Comment: No, I do not. I would like add the public schema to the autovacuum search_path if I knew how to do that, but I found nothing in the documentation to that effect (just that they removed it from there, but no way to put it back, I would not like to downgrade or recompile postgres). I could also try to transfer the unaccent extension to the pg_catalog schema, but that is also seemingly impossible.

Comment: The `search_path` for autovacuum has been changed for security reasons. I don't expect them to revert that change nor to offer users the unsafe option to do so. Have you tried to schema-qualify function and dictionary as suggested?

Comment: Schema-qualifying need application-side change which I am not sure I can make. Also, it needs a complete database rebuild using the new unaccent function. I may try it later, but not in the very near future. The security measure does not really apply to me, as I have a single database with a single user and access control is all in the application, so it is more annoying than useful to me; it would be nice to be able to turn it off.

Comment: Actually, you can change the function definition with `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ...` ***without*** rebuilding anything. Expression indexes rely on the immutability of the used function and are not stopping you. If you make sure that the function keeps using the same function & dictionary, indexes keep working properly. (You can't `DROP` the function, though.)

Answer (score 3):

You are obviously using a fake-`IMMUTABLE` function wrapper for `unaccent()` to use it in indexes. It's based on the search dictionary "unaccent" implicitly or explicitly. The dictionary to be used can be provided as optional first function parameter to `unaccent()`. The name of the dictionary can be schema-qualified. Else it needs to reside in one of the schemas of the current [**`search_path`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860).

I do not advise to manipulate the function `unaccent()` provided by the extension. Instead, create and use a wrapper function like instructed here:

- [Does PostgreSQL support “accent insensitive” collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216)

In your case, the additional module `unaccent` might be installed in a schema that's missing from the `search_path` of the session reporting these errors. When you try manually, you do that in a session where the `search_path` *includes* that same schema, so no error there.

You can either set your `search_path` to include the schema of the extension in all sessions, or schema-qualify the dictionary in the function calls of `unaccent()`.

Security for client programs has been tightened with **Postgres 10.3 / 9.6.8** etc. Now you *need* to schema-qualify function and dictionary when used in any indexes - as demonstrated in the linked answer above.

The [release notes for Postgres 10.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-10-3.html):

> Also, the changes described in the second changelog entry below may
>   **cause functions used in index expressions or materialized views to
>   fail during auto-analyze**, or when reloading from a dump. After
>   upgrading, monitor the server logs for such problems, and fix affected
>   functions.
>
> ...
>
> - Avoid use of insecure search_path settings in pg_dump and other client programs (Noah Misch, Tom Lane)
>
>   pg_dump, pg_upgrade, vacuumdb and other PostgreSQL-provided
>     applications were themselves vulnerable to the type of hijacking
>     described in the previous changelog entry; since these applications
>     are commonly run by superusers, they present particularly attractive
>     targets. To make them secure whether or not the installation as a
>     whole has been secured, modify them to **include only the pg_catalog
>     schema in their search_path settings. Autovacuum worker processes now
>     do the same, as well.**
>
>   **In cases where user-provided functions are indirectly executed by
>     these programs — for example, user-provided functions in index
>     expressions — the tighter search_path may result in errors, which will
>     need to be corrected by adjusting those user-provided functions to not
>     assume anything about what search path they are invoked under.** That
>     has always been good practice, but now it will be necessary for
>     correct behavior.

**Bold** emphasis mine.

See the special mention of **auto-analyze** and **autovacuum**? To fix, schema-qualify function name and dictionary in the `unaccent()` call of the wrapper function used in your index(es) as [demonstrated in the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216). Like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_unaccent(text)
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
SELECT public.unaccent('public.unaccent', $1)  -- schema-qualify function and dictionary
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

You can change an existing function definition with `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ...` without rebuilding existing indexes based on it. Make sure the function keeps using the same function & dictionary, then indexes keep working properly without `REINDEX`. (You can't `DROP` the function, though, while it's used in an index.)

Moving the unaccent module to the system catalog `pg_catalog` also works. Then everything is in the `search_path` automatically. [You ended up doing so](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202490/text-search-dictionary-unaccent-does-not-exist-entries-in-postgres-log-supp/202586?noredirect=1#comment423710_202586), but I do ***not*** advocate that. Messing with system catalogs is generally discouraged and can easily damage your installation if you don't know exactly what you are doing.

Related:

- [Error when creating unaccent extension on PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100638/error-when-creating-unaccent-extension-on-postgresql/12101055#12101055)

---

The search dictionary "unaccent" is also regularly used by ***text search configurations*** in full text search. Related:

- [Get partial match from GIN indexed TSVECTOR column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157951/get-partial-match-from-gin-indexed-tsvector-column/157982#157982)
- [Finding the most commonly used non-stop words in a column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145016/finding-the-most-commonly-used-non-stop-words-in-a-column/186754#186754)

Comment: The other idea is most probably not true, as it was not an "upgrade" in the strict sense of the word, but a recreation of the database in postgres 10.

Comment: @P.Péter: Did you re-install the additional module unaccent in the process? I added some more above.

Comment: Of course I installed that extension. It is actually included in the official debian postgres server package (`postgresql-10`), so I cannot really not install it. :) Also, if I did not have it installed, then it really coudn't work properly, no matter what session the query would run. I will try to look into your `search_path` hypothesis, but I will have to identify the `search_path` during _automatic analyze_.

Comment: In light of the fix in pg 10.3, I think my first hypothesis idea with the search_path was a good lead. Consider the update.

Comment: As I wrote in my question, I am already on 10.3 (Debian 10.3-1.pgdg80+1).

Comment: @P.Péter: .. which means you are affected by the tightened security measures.

Comment: If I have a backup file which I can't modify, and I'm getting this error, what should I do? I'm trying to restore as `postgres` and I'm quite sure unaccent is in the search path.

Comment: @Thom: You may need to schema-qualify the function (*and* dictionary). Please post a new question with your exact details. You can always link to this one for reference.

Comment: `ALTER EXTENSION unaccent SET SCHEMA pg_catalog;` did the trick for me. This seemed to be the smallest change, so I went with that. This is not explicitly offered in this answer, but can be deduced from it. It may be useful to include it somehow explicitly.

Comment: @P.Péter: Useful information, I added a pointer to your comment. But I would *not* advocate this route.