# Postgres full text search on words, not lexemes

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I've got a table with columns of text that I'd like to search by *word*, not *lexeme*. More to the point, that I'd like to have indexed by word rather than lexeme. We've got error dumps with a lot of code references, which don't work well with any natural language dictionary.

Is there a way in Postgres to have FTS parse by word boundaries without resolving words to lexemes? If I have to define a list of boundary characters and a catalog of skip words, that could be fine. Does this require crafting some kind of custom dictionary, or is there something already like this available?

I keep thinking I'm missing something obvious, and then not finding it.

For the minute, trigram indexes are okay, but I would really prefer what amounts to a unique keyword parser for the text.

Postgres 11.4 on RDS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use the `simple` text search configuration, which works with the [**`simple`** dictionary](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SIMPLE-DICTIONARY) and does not do any stemming:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl USING GIN (to_tsvector('simple', data));
```

And query accordingly:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  to_tsvector('simple', data) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'foo');
```

Related:

- [Get partial match from GIN indexed TSVECTOR column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157951/get-partial-match-from-gin-indexed-tsvector-column/157982#157982)
- [Finding the most commonly used non-stop words in a column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145016/finding-the-most-commonly-used-non-stop-words-in-a-column/186754#186754)
- [PostgreSQL full text search on many columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164000/postgresql-full-text-search-on-many-columns/164081#164081)

Comment: Fantastic! I was missing something obvious. I've just used your clear and simple instructions and, yeah, it's great. Very fast, very easy to use.